# Set localPlayer.authenticateHandler method pointer to global method

Tags: ios, objective-c, game-center

I dont want to set "localPlayer.authenticateHandler" locally like that as I have ARC off and I think something is going wack in that mode. (Its for Unity3D so ARC must be off).

```
localPlayer.authenticateHandler = ^(UIViewController *viewController, NSError *error)
{
    ....
};
```

I want to try setting it like:

```
localPlayer.authenticateHandler = myCallback;
```

But how do I do this with ObjC syntax?  This would be super easy in C#, C++... but how in ObjC?

Comment: http://goshdarnblocksyntax.com

Comment: Figured out this had nothing to do with the issue.